# How to send a byte array file in body of a POST rest call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

We have a JSON request coming in from one microservice like below:

```
"attachment": {
    "attachmentName": "AttacmentTest2023-04-03T07:45:31.442-07:00.pdf",
    "attachmentData": "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q="
}
```

the other microservice will receive the above JSON request and have to pass this attachment as a file as shown below with attachmentName that is coming in JSON request in POST rest call to an other service.

[image]

Could you please help me how I can achieve this in springboot.

I tried the below logic but it is throwing the error **"Must have at least one MIME part with a filename"**

```
    public String Test(RequestBody requestBody) throws RFConnectionException {
        ResponseEntity<String> response;
        try {
        
            byte[] attachmentData = requestBody.getBody().getAttachment().getAttachmentData();
            String attachmentName = requestBody.getBody().getAttachment().getAttachmentName();
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(attachmentData);
            body.add("file", resource);

            // Set the content type header
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            headers.setContentDispositionFormData("file", attachmentName);

            // Create the HTTP entity with the form data and headers
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

            // Send the POST request and retrieve the response
            response = restTemplate.postForEntity(config.getAttachmentUrl(), requestEntity, String.class);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
              log.error("Exception occurred while calling: " + exception.getMessage());
              throw new RFConnectionException("Error while getting response::" + exception.getMessage());
        }
        return response.getBody();
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the log content as well?

Comment: The MIME type is passed in the Content-Type header. So you can modify your headers like this `headers.add("Content-Type", multipart/form-data);`, `headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+attachmentName);` and try.